# Using context variable to name a "section" instead of passing a value

Tags: django

In the following view, the context variable is used to mark the 'section' as 'dashboard'(I think).

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

This then allows me to say `{% if section == 'whatever' %}`, for example:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
      <ul class = 'menu'>
        <li {% if section == 'dashboard' %} class='selected' {% endif %}>
          <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">My Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        ... continues
    </ul>
   {% endif %}
```

Now if the `dashboard` view is called, `.selected` will be applied to the 'Dashboard' link (change color to show it's active). I get what it is doing, just don't understand how this works. I have only seen values passed in the context i.e. `{'number': 8}`. How exactly does django keep track of this naming system? It does not seem to be adding a class or anything of the sorts.

Comment: When you say **"this naming system"** you are referring to `url 'dashboard'` right?

Comment: No, though that is partly why I was confused. I do have a url with `name='dashboard'`, but I don't think that is being referenced here. I guess I am creating a variable `section` and assigning it the value 'dashboard' when the user calls the `dashboard` view. Say I have a `gallery` view I can then change it to `{'section': 'gallery"}` when said view is called. @ReinstateMonica

Comment: Also, I guess this is not a 'naming system' as I had thought, I am just assigning a string value and using it as a 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every key in the `context` dictionary that is passed to the template is transformed into a variable with that very same name that is available to the template at the moment of rendering.

For example if you render a template with a context dict such as:

```py
{
    'key1': 'somevalue1',
    'key2': 'somevalue2',
    'key3': 'somevalue3',
}
```

in the template, at rendering time, you will have three variables called `key1`, `key2` and `key3` with the corresponding values.

So what is happening in your code is that when you call the view `dashboard()` this view renders the template your view calls the `render()` method which in turn takes the template code defined in the html file you pass to it and converts this code into pure html by executing the django template code in a context where a variable `section` has been created and assigned the value `'dashboard'` (because that's what you passed to `render()` as the `context` param)

Comment: With the goal of highlighting the current active section (which is what I'm doing in the book I am reading) I can see how this is a better route than adding a class name to each individual html file and then checking to see which page the user is on using javascript. Thanks for the answer this makes sense.